# Handle two Gesture Recognizer simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

The problem is quite simple: I have a `ViewController` on which I have a `GestureRecognizer`:

```
    panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
              action: #selector(handlePan(gestureRecognizer:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGR)
```

In this `ViewController` I also have a `class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController` on which I have the "swipe-to-delete"-function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Löschen") {[weak self] _, _, completionHandler in
        self!.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)
    completionHandler(true)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
}
```

Here is a Video of my `panGR` in action: [Screenvideo](https://gofile.io/d/j6b4Ab)

This is my `handlePan` function:

```
// handle swqipe down gesture
@objc private func handlePan(gestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // calculate the progress based on how far the user moved
    let translation = panGR.translation(in: nil)
    let progress = translation.y / 2 / view.bounds.height

  switch panGR.state {
  case .began:
    // begin the transition as normal
    self.dismissView()
    break
  case .changed:

    Hero.shared.update(progress)

  default:
    // finish or cancel the transition based on the progress and user's touch velocity
       if progress + panGR.velocity(in: nil).y / view.bounds.height > 0.3 {
        self.dismissView()
         Hero.shared.finish()
       } else {
         Hero.shared.cancel()
       }
  }
}
```

The problem is that these two collide. The "swipe-to-delete" only works if I disable the other `GestureRecognizer`. Why is that and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you let me know why are you adding UIPanGestureRecognizer and what are you handling in handlePan()? Is the table view part of the view ? Better to separate the tableview and the view you want to achieve the UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: @Nandish have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Mitesh Mistri I got it working. One more thing that was missing was a function to disable the `panGR` inside the `tableView` because otherwise the user wouldnt be able to scroll. These are the two function that made it work:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if self.theTableView.view.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: self.theTableView.view)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try this.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

in viewDidLoad

```
yourGesture.delegate = self
```

and finally

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true

    // If you wish to do conditionally.
    /*if (gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer || gestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }*/
}
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything :( maybe because my `tableView` is in a  custom `Class` ?

Comment: I tried it again with your solution and it kind of works but it feels really clunky. The `panGR` should not be active inside the `tableView`  because I can not scroll anymore with it

Comment: figured it out! its working now, check out my answer. I will give you the bounty anyway as your solution fixed the main issue here, thanks

Comment: Chris thanks, man. Good to hear my solution worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

When you do pan gesture on top of the view the gesture pan recognizer will be invoked. If the tableview is part of the view the gesture handlePan will be called when you try to do swipe-to-delete function.

If you want 2 separate behavior then separate the part of the view in which you want gesture handlePan to execute and tableview where you want swipe-to-delete function to execute.

Something like below :

```
   panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
          action: #selector(handlePan(gestureRecognizer:)))
   gestureView.addGestureRecognizer(panGR)
   view.addSubView(gestureView)
```

EDIT: You can also get the location/co-ordinates of the location pressed and you can calculate which areas to ignore.

```
    currentLocation = gesture.location(in: self.view)
```

Comment: did you have a look at the video? The `panGR` should be everywhere but the `tableView`

Comment: I saw it now and updated the answer? If that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Normally this is simple,

Firstly , you don't need to add a gesture recognizer to the view,

we already have the function "touchesBegan" which Tells this object that one or more new touches occurred in a view or window.

so in your code you just need to use it instead of the gesture recognizer and it will works.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {
  
    
    let tableView:UITableView = {
     let table =  UITableView()
        table.backgroundColor = .blue
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    //    tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height/2, width: view.frame.width, height:view.frame.height/2 )
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return 20
      }
      
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
          cell.backgroundColor = .blue
          return cell
      }
      

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }// we store the touch
        
        let location = touch.location(in: view)//we retrieve the location of the touch
        
        if view.bounds.contains(location){//we check if our touch is inside our view
            
            // if our touch is inside  the view ,do the action you wanted to do with your gesture recognizer
            print("inside the view, outside tableView(Controller)")
        }else{
            // else here means here that  this is not inside the view, so it is inside  the tableView(Controller)
            // if this is not inside the view, you can select tableView,rows,swipe-to-delete etc, basically do whatever action you want with it
        }
    }
   
    
  
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure how I should use this. I updated my question and provided the `code` for my `handlePan` - function. Another thing is that I have a seperated custom `tableView`- Class in which I handle all the `tableView-methods` (also the swipe to delete)